# Find the probability density function of the random variable $u=u(y)=\sqrt{y+1}$ ,y with known probability density function

Tags: statistics, random-variables, density-function

Find the probability density function of the random variable $u=u(y)=\sqrt{y+1} \;$, y with known probability density function

$$f(y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{1}{2\beta}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}}  &\quad\text{if} \; y \gt 0 \\
       \frac{1}{2} &\quad\text{if} \; -1 \lt y \lt 0 \\ 
     \end{cases}$$

What I did is, I used the change of variable theorem; $ g(u)=\rvert \frac{dy}{du}\lvert f(y(u))$

$$u=\sqrt{1+y} \implies y=u^{2}-1 \\
     \rvert \frac{dy}{du}\lvert = 2u \\
 \implies g(u)= 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{2u}{2\beta}e^{\frac{-u^{2}+1}{\beta}}  &\quad\text{if} \; u \gt 1 \\
       \frac{2u}{2} &\quad\text{if} \; 0 \lt u \lt 1 \\ 
     \end{cases} \\
  \implies g(u)= 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{u}{\beta}e^{\frac{-u^{2}+1}{\beta}}  &\quad\text{if} \; u \gt 1 \\
       u &\quad\text{if} \; 0 \lt u \lt 1 \\ 
     \end{cases} $$

Finally, I don't know if the procedure is correct or I'm missing something since u is defined as a square root. Also don't know if the limits are correct either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $f(y)=$ instead of $f(x)=$?

Comment: Since the  square root function is a one-to-one function there is no problem. It looks all fine to me.

Comment: @callculus Yes, you are correct, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. You can make a sanity check: $\int_0^{\infty} g(u) \,du=1$